# Why java session.getAttribute() value null while accessing ionic1

Tags: java, spring, ionic-framework, cross-platform

On server side I'm using Java and on the client side Ionic1.

I'm setting Java object to session like this:

```
session.setAttribute("userId", userObj.getUserId());
```

After setting session i need to get that session in another method, that time I'm using like this

```
Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");
```

Here if i send request from mobile to server I will get session.getAttribute value.

But I sent request from browser to server that time I will get session.getAttribute value is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the getAttribute() only after the session has been created. Its a common mistake to access the session attributes when no session exists.
Basically, validate and make sure session exists and that the attribute value has been set in the application flow before trying to get the session attributes.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);  
// true will create a session is does not already exists
if(session != null) {
    // get your session attributes here.
    // Your Session Attributes should be set before you're trying to access them
}
```